# How does Django serve media files?

Tags: django, file, static

I have set up a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) application that uses images. I think I have set up the media settings MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL correctly. However the images don't show up. Do you know what can be the problem?

Let consider this example:

The image files are under **/home/www/media/app/photos** and we are trying to request http://example.com/photos/123.jpg

Should I use these settings?

```
MEDIA\_ROOT = /home/www/media

MEDIA_URL = http://example.com/app
```

**UPDATE:** Forgot to mention that I'm using built-in development server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Serving static content from Django is **discouraged** from the developer themselves (if I'm not wrong, it only works when in debug mode). You should use a dedicated web server, instead.

If you really need to do that, anyway, read the documentation on [how to serve static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 15):

**FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY**

You can setup a static media server for use with their development server by doing this in your `urls.py` file. I have attached the code showing how I use it (along with the forced DEBUG conditionals.)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *      

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    (r'^$', 'views.index'),            

    # Accounts
    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'views.user_login'),
    (r'^accounts/logout/$', 'views.user_logout'),

    # Contrib Modules
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
)

if settings.DEBUG :
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

I place my `MEDIA_ROOT` in a subdirectory of html/media and link to it as such in `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'html/media/').replace('\\','/')
```

After development is finished, the project gets deployed to the web server where static media files are then served by [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) using  directives.

Comment: In your templates though, how would you reference a CSS file or image file? Say you had your css at html/media/styles.css.

Answer (score 9):

You can just add those lines to your urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
    ]
```

Comment: This is the most up-to-dated solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct way of showing image files with ImageField. Imagine we have a user profile picture:

models.py:

```
UserProfile:
    profilePic= models.ImageField( upload_to='PATH_TO_UPLOAD', blank=True, null=True)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'FULL_PATH_OF_MEDIA'
MEDIA_URL = 'URL_OF_MEDIA'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
.
.
.
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

PATH_TO_UPLOAD is the path which user upload data goes. This is sub-directory of FULL_PATH_OF_MEDIA, which means the uploaded file will have

```
FULL_PATH_OF_MEDIA/PATH_TO_UPLOAD
```

full path.Now this content can be accessed at this url:

```
SITE_NAME/URL_OF_MEDIA/PATH_TO_UPLOAD
```

I also recommend reading this on [static_files vs media_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456817/django-when-should-i-use-media-root-or-static-root)

[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: Please keep in mind that this will work only if DEBUG = True

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are getting the Django 404 page. Try directly accessing one of your images and see if that's happening.

If so, your need to configure your web server to *not* send requests within your media hierarchy to Django but to instead serve them directly. Here is a snip from my Apache conf file. The first section tells Apache to send everything to Django. The second section has "SetHandler None" which says "handle stuff under /media in the normal way."

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/ for all the exciting details.

Partial httpd.conf file for PrinceOfPinot.com (AKA pop):

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonAutoReload Off
    PythonDebug Off
    PythonPath "['/var/www/production/pop', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
</Location>

<Location "/media">
    SetHandler None
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/x-javascript
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that the original question is with the dev server, but for anyone else who is looking for a production environment answer:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/ provides a guide on how to have django serve files in a production environment. From the tone of the guide, it does seem to imply that it is best to have a separate web server to handle the files or use mod_wsgi with Apache