# how to set django static image

Tags: django

I have a view and template called index.html.

I have a image which is broken form.I saw django docs,which was n't clear to me.

How do,i make my image to appear.I m asking ,while development.image is in ,this URL /home/logic/quote/hummingbird.gif'

Comment: Not exactly sure what you asking for. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear but I suspect that you are having trouble serving static files using the Django built-in web server. Have a look at the following StackOverflow Questions:

1. [Django and Serving Static Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179453/django-and-serving-static-files)
2. [How does Django serve media files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402841/how-does-django-serve-media-files)
3. [Django: how do you serve media / stylesheets and link to them within templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446026/django-how-do-you-serve-media-stylesheets-and-link-to-them-within-templates)

Answer (score -1):

what about writing an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that makes something simmilar to:

```
if settings.debug=True:
    return localimage
else:
    return serverimage
```