# Saving Image File in particular directory in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I am using Python PIL library in Django Rest Framework for building qr code and saving it to static directory.

```
  def generate_qr(self, name):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
        box_size=15,
        border=5
    )
    qr.add_data(name)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    img.save(settings.STATIC_ROOT+"/asset-tags/name.png")
    return(name+ '.png')
```

settings.py for media and static urls:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = "/mediafiles/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mediafiles")
```

But while saving it throws an error saying /usr/app/static/name.png : no file or directory.
I am creating new file so how can it find the image in given folder.

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you set `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`? Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) on how to serve `MEDIA_FILES`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Django serve media files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402841/how-does-django-serve-media-files)

Comment: I have set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT. I have updated the question with that. And the docs you shared above will work for saving image as well?

Comment: Images should be saved inside `MEDIA_ROOT`, with your settings inside `mediafiles` directory. Try with `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: What is the type of `img` ?

Comment: img is an object of PIL library

Comment: Image can be overwritten. But new image isn't able to save there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *qrcode* package or *Pillow* package won't create a directory if it doesn't exist. So, as per your settings, the **`STATIC_ROOT`** is located at **`/staticfiles`** and make sure that the directory named **`staticfiles`** (and it's sub-directories) exists before runs your script.

In other words, the statement **`img.save(settings.STATIC_ROOT+"/asset-tags/name.png")`** supposed to be save the QR code image under this path **`/staticfiles/asset-tags/name.png`** and make sure the directory **`/staticfiles/asset-tags/`** exists in your project path.

**NOTE:** Use **`settings.MEDIA_ROOT`** instead of `settings.STATIC_ROOT` would be more appropriate.

Comment: plus saving it inside `MEDIA_ROOT` would be more appropriate. `img.save(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"/asset-tags/"+"name.png")`, will save it inside `/mediafiles/asset-tags/`